# Preventing hexadecimal strings in YAML from loading as float/int in Python

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to make some changes in a YAML file using python.
I have a file with the structure:

```
name:
  mode: value
```

The value is a number of hex digits. 
I do:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
f = open('C:\\file.yaml', 'r')
data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
```

then change several values and dump it back:

```
with open('C:\\file.yaml', 'w') as out_yaml:
     yaml.dump(in_data, out_yaml, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, explicit_start=True)
```

And here I have a problem - some values were loaded as int or float and after dump I get values such as `.inf` or `9.4014e+40` e.g. from YAML:

```
name:
  mode1: 8578E877
  mode2: 94014E36
```

How can I preserve the result values from this kind of conversion?

Comment: The first value is outside the range expressible by Python floats (IEEE 754 doubles) and the second is unchanged in value.

Comment: I know but I need these values to be same (maybe load them as string?)

Comment: Please update this to be a [mcve] -- including actual test data that is misparsed, in code someone can copy-and-paste to see the problem themselves (so ideally, parsing from a string rather than a file so one need only copy-and-paste to test). And make the title more specific to the question.

Comment: ...I've done the title update, but the edit is on you.

Comment: @Mike After all this well mentioned mangling of your title through contributed edits, it might be that changing it to "*Preventing hexadecimal strings in YAML from loading as float/int in Python*" is more appropriate.

Comment: @Anthon yes, I think you're right, I meant to ask exactly this question))

Answer (score 3):

You state "The value is a number of hexdigits" and "some values were loaded as int or float". And according to the [YAML 1.2. Core Schema](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) used for round-trip-loading (but also in the simpler JSON schema): those scalars **are**  `int` resp. `float` and not strings.

If you would try to dump a structure with various character combination as strings:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

data = dict(
    name=dict(
        teny='decade',
        tbig='8578E877',
        mode='94014E36',
        ints='12345',
        Bool='True',
    )
)
yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you would get:

```
name:
  teny: decade
  tbig: '8578E877'
  mode: '94014E36'
  ints: '12345'
  Bool: 'True'
```

As you can see only `decade` makes it out as an unquoted scalar, and the reason for this is that the others can be misinterpreted if not quoted.

That is why, if you ever look at how the `RoundTripLoader` and `RoundTripDumper` (and their safe and unsafe counterparts) are constructed you can see that **both** are derived from the `Resolver`. Even when dumping a value, the patterns from the schema are matched against the regular expressions attached to the `Resolver`, to make sure it will not be loaded back as a special type. As the quoted `True` in the YAML output indicates this applies to other types than `int` and `float` as well.

The easy solution is to quote the combination of hex digits in your YAML input:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

yaml_str = """\
name:
  tbig: '8578E877'
  mode: '94014E36'
"""

data = yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
print(data['name']['tbig'], data['name']['mode'], end='\n----\n')
yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

will print:

```
8578E877 94014E36
----
name:
  tbig: '8578E877'
  mode: '94014E36'
```

It is possible to prevent these scalar strings from loading as `int` resp. `float`. If you do so by changing the regular expressions attached to `Resolver` your program will load **and dump** those in a way no longer adhering to the core schema, so the quotes are not going to be attached on dump automatically when necessary.

If you have too many values in an existing YAML file to change by hand, and want to do a one off conversion, you'll need to use a `Loader` that has a resolver doesn't use those patterns. Fortunately the `BaseLoader` does so:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

yaml_str = """\
name:
  tbig: 8578E877
  mode: 94014E36
  teny: DECADE
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, yaml.loader.BaseLoader)
yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
name:
  tbig: '8578E877'
  mode: '94014E36'
  teny: DECADE
```

adding quotes only where necessary. After that one-time load-dump you can use the normal round-trip or safe loader on that file.

---

The keys in the YAML output for the first example I gave were the same order as those given in the dict. That was so for Python 3.6, but not when run with 2.7. If you start from a Python data structure and want to control that output order use `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` instead of a dict.

Comment: @Mike Welcome to [so]. Thanks (in comments or in questions) are not really necessary. Show your appreciation through upvotes (once you have 15 reputation) and consider accepting (clicking the V to the left of the answer) if such an answer resolves your issue. That is also an indication for others that your original question has been answered. You can always change that if a better answer comes along.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do I understand right that I need to start with loading yaml file using BaseLoader (I have several thousands of those values) and dump it back so all values got quoted. Then change the regular expressions attached to Resolver?

Comment: @Mike No you only need to do the first part. Once the appropriate values are written out quoted, they will load correctly using `yaml.round_trip_load(f)`. No need to mess with the regular expressions if you "improve" your YAML files once.

Comment: nice! I'll try it later.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that if you have any floats and ints in your file that are intended to be so, those will be loaded as strings using BaseLoader as welll, and quoted on output. Best way to solve that is walk recursively over your data structure, test each string value and if they should be a float (or int or bool) do the conversion, then write out the data. It is cumbersome, but you only need to do so once. Don't overwrite your input file until the conversion is perfect!

Comment: no, there aren't any. I want to load the data as strings, make some changes and write it back without any quotes.

Comment: That is probably easiest achieved by doing `f.write(yaml.round_trip_dump(data).replace("'", "")`, because `round_trip_dump` ** will add those quotes unless you want to start mucking with the regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

using pyaml you can prevent "intelligent" interpretation of the inputs using the yaml.BaseLoader

```py
import yaml
with open("your_file.yaml", encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
```

Comment: Sure, but then you are completely disabling all interpretation and this might have unintended effects depending on the assumptions made elsewhere in your codebase.